# How to Vertically holster beard-hair trimmer & electric shaver, and suspend it using a shelf over bathroom counter?

Tags: personal-care, comfort, efficiency, bathroom, storage

Bathroom counter, with electrical socket, mirror & glass shelves on adjoining wall. 
Also, electric shaver at bottom of pic on Counter
 
[image: electric beard hair trimmer]
Electric trimmer, depicting shape etc

Now, based on something I saw online it suggested double hooks (hardware fittings)/ something that looked like or looks like guitar hangers.

[image: guitar hanger hook stand sample images]

Lets assume we may not be allowed to drill these holes & screws for such hooks or something DIY that has similar Shape/ Structure.

In what ways/ ideas could I suspend both devices over the counter;
- saving counter space and
- keeping devices out of harms way
- most importantly; quick gun ergonomic access & usage
- decluttered space

Could I DIY a metal hanger or some plastic object to use the Glass Shelf as a support/ beam?

Suction cups tend to spoil and be unreliable after some time, is what I read a lot online.

Comment: Maybe check out Sugru Moldable Glue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was trying to hack something into such a hook structure from question but I couldn't find the metal clothes hangers we used to have before.

I found these Flexible Spider stands whose legs can be shaped to mount smart phones on tables or in a car etc.

I just Folded them in a similar way, ideally I'd hope for longer bending at the back. It's a bit bouncy but pretty stable.

Let's see if I can improve on it with more shaping and maybe a longer & thicker rod/ wire from a metal hanger if I can find one

Update: I did find a metal wire clothes hanger that I'm looking to bend and shape into something with 2 open loops and a tether that goes back and hooks through the gap between shelf & wall and below as well.

Picture: 
[image: spider stand folded to guitar hanger style]
Update slightly improved:
[image: spider stand to mount electric hair beard trimmer shaver]

Answer (score 1):

In this environment, I would use stacking desk trays. They are fairly stable and do not need to be attached to a wall.

[image]

Your smaller bathroom items could become hard to reach at the back of a bottom/middle tray, so purchase desk trays that open from the long side, rather than the shorter side. Taller desk trays improve accessibility too.

The first picture in your question shows a blue-green plastic box.  That could go on top of the topmost tray, with the other items on the "shelves" beneath it. Rigging up homemade drawers would be simple too: just slide a low-edged plastic box into each of the "shelves", then draw it out halfway to fill it with smaller items. (Be careful not to draw it out the whole way, as it will just fall off the "shelf" and spill its contents!)

You should be able to find affordable stacking desk trays in a variety of colors, sizes, and designs.

Comment: @stan / that is in progress - will be clearing the crap / my organisation gets messed up by my parents maid/ help. Brett - thank you for the effort but you are way off on what's needed, what I want in quick get & put, keep vertical and zero floor space for the devices. I need those hooks/ hangers or something similar, that works like a quick gun holster

Comment: Plus there's more shelves above that glass shelf, that's not an issue or lack there off. Just want to holster/ suspend the 2 devices so that their charging cables and adapters are also hanging in air below them. Quick Gun

Answer (score 1):

How about a car phone holder that grabs the phone like this one:

[image: phone holder suction cup]

[image: phone holder clip]

You can mount it on the wall or on glass and the 'hands' can be adjusted to hold your trimmer.

Comment: Thought about them but phones are flat in design and most holders are designed to hold flat slim phones. As you may notice I posted varying angled pic of the shaver/ trimmer to show they are thicker and not flat. Do share if you find an exception to this.

Comment: @AlexS Not all of these have small hands! There are others, like this for example http://bpc.h-cdn.co/assets/16/13/480x480/gallery-1459372648-usa-gear-vent-car-mount.jpg that can hold your trimmer. I think it's worth going to a store and seeing what they have.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a looksie online and offline. Doubtful there's many that can hold the roundish structure from bottom and sides. Ps: You might want to update the answer with images & links of some best examples you found. Future users could upvote as well. I'll add some if I find a fitting one

Comment: I have kept this picture because it has the sucction cup bottom but I'll add the other with bigger hands as well

Comment: Thanks - I google image searched and found the larger issue would be the bottom of such mount not being deep and wide enough to hold device. And the side walls would be too wide to hold the trimmer. Again will try to find and see. Thanks - You can add more images to answer than one. Maybe collage as I've done in question

Answer (score 0):

Both the items you wish to store have power cords.

The items are quite light and can be hung (**vertically**) from 'S' shaped hooks from the shelf you show. Many if not all hair stylist powered tools have a hole molded into the appliance end of the cord for hanging.

If your tools do not have such a hole, a wire loop can be made and attached to the cord.

Good luck.

Comment: Hanging inverted has the added benefit of letting particulate (dirt) fall from the clipper rather than further into the blades or even into the motor eventually - this advice from Wahl (one of the largest manufacturers of such equipment.)

Comment: Pic examples of appliance end cord hole for upside down hang?

Comment: @AlexS Yes. There are many of them online.

Comment: Do update into your answer.