# Degunk & clean these silicone/ rubbery plastic covered flexible metal spider stands in a dusty hot humid asian metro city?

Tags: cleaning, bathroom, bedroom

I’ll be linking this to a prev hack that got me to create these hacks.

[How to Vertically holster beard-hair trimmer & electric shaver, and suspend it using a shelf over bathroom counter?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17253/how-vertically-holster-electric-shaver-beard-hair-trimmer-suspended-maybe-u)

Now I’m wondering what are better ways to undo the sticky dust / gunk that gathers in hot humid sticky asian metro cities.

2 on the left are used within the Bathroom while the right blue in the bedroom so its dust is less visible and lighter, but not visible in the current pic and lighting.

PS: Blue will definitely need a differently lit pics.

Posting from phone for pics so update via PC for any typos or formatting issues.

Will also zoom into them and see if they’re clear enough to show or will try with better pics and update.

[image: In bathroom under CFL]

[image: in day light shade]

Forced flash makes it seem dark.

[image]

Comment: Scrub them in dish soap with a dish brush.

Comment: What did you already try? You wondered what are better ways… better than what?

Comment: I do not know the materials so I do not dare. Updating with pics. Maybe they show more.

Comment: That has not much to do with “dusty hot humid Asian city” and a lot more with “humid environment where dust gets caked on” - aka a bathroom. Water and dish soap and some gentle rubbing should do the trick.

Comment: @Stephie - Thanks will try it out. It's there even outside the bathroom on the blue one - less dark/ intense but a film of a lighter shade. Unable to make it visible in the pic. Any caution with regard to the metal underneath/ within.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Thanks will try it out. Any caution with regard to the metal underneath/ within.

Comment: It might not be rustproof. I suggest bending the strands so they all point downward, and not to immerse the gripper such that they point upwards. Allow to dry in the same orientation so that water doesn't find its way between the stiffener wire and the rubber coating. Try with *one* gripper, before risking them all.

Answer (score 1):

Wash them.

Periodically (when desired), rinse the offending object(s) under hot running water from the sink faucet and replace. For stubborn cases, swish (a technical term) the gizmos in hot soapy water and rinse with clear hot water. Dry them. Reinstall them.

Washing an object is not considered a Lifehack, by the way.

Good luck.

Comment: Washing is the answer. (But doesn't get many points.) I find a gentle cleaning spray (not one with bleach) should provide enough lubrication/detergent if you want to wash in situ, or place in water.

Comment: @StuartF The points are nice; but, the real incentive is to find a solution to the problem. Comments aren't answers that can be voted upon; so, be as proactive as you can. Jump in! Enjoy yourself. Have fun. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

place them in a dishwashing machine and run them on the standard cycle using supermarket dishwashing machine powder.